# Getting argumenterror when trying to display video on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, video, carrierwave

I wanted to let users upload a video, so I used carrierwave to add that functionality. When I run it, I get the following error[image]

My userinfo index code:

```
<h1>YOUR PROFILE IS HERE</h1>

<% @userinfors.each do |post|%>
    <%= video_tag post.video_url.to_s :controls =>true %>
<%end%>
```

My userinfo controller:

```
class UserinfosController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @userinfors = Userinfo.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @userinformation = Userinfo.new
    end

    def create
        @userinformation = Userinfo.new(userinfo_params)
        if @userinformation.save
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render 'new'
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private
        def userinfo_params
            params.require(:userinfo).permit(:name, :email, :college, :gpa, :major, :video)
        end
end
```

My userinfo model:

```
class Userinfo < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    mount_uploader :video, VideoUploader 
end
```

The video_uploader file created for carrierwave:

```
class VideoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

end
```

My migration file to add videos to userinfo model:

```
class AddVideoToUserinfo < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :userinfos, :video, :string
  end
end
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a comma:

```
video_tag(post.video_url.to_s, :controls => true)
```

Comment: Thank you! The error disappeared and the video shows up but doesn't play. It can be downloaded and the video gets downloaded, so I know it loads. The controls (play button, time, and download button) shows up. From the code, do you see why that's a problem, or should I post another question for that issue and give you the link here so you can help me out?

Comment: Sorry, looks like a browser / HTML issue.